# Creating chart of only certain rows

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Using Google Sheets, is there a way to create charts for only certain rows?

I have created some reports, but when the source list is sorted differently the report breaks because of using the data source as `'SourceTab'!A2:X2`.  In the source tab I have about 60+ rows, but only want to report on certain rows.

I thought I could add a column to each row to create groupings, then in the chart call those groupings to create the reports.

Comment: I try this, but the source is a number of columns.  So, for say, group 2 the values to be graphed are in the range `H9:CA9` and growing.

Comment: And? `=QUERY(myOtherSheet!H9:1000, "select * where ....", 1)`

Comment: it seems I would have to maintain a query for each group of charts.  So say out of the 60 rows I want charts by groupings, 1-?... I was hoping there was a way to put the formula in the chart data source and not having to maintain yet another sheet.

Comment: With a website/html page you can extract what you desire by defining various [`DataView`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView)s from the same underlying DataTable. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add a column to each row to create groupings` sounds a good idea. Just create your chart from all available data then filter your data to select only the rows flagged in that column.

Answer (score 0):

you can **`QUERY()`** them out like this:

```
=QUERY({2:2; 4:5; 8:8}, "select *", 0)
```

[image]